# is my async lambda usage correct in the cache aside pattern?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am bit confused with async and Lambda function.

I have an old CacheHelper function (basically a cache aside pattern), which does this:

```
public static T GetOrAdd<T>(Func<Task<T>> builder, TimeSpan expiresIn, bool ignoreNullValues, params string[] keys)
{
      ////check if the cache item is available
       xxxx
      //// if not, call the builder function to get fresh
      var item = builder().Result;
      //// add to cache and return the item
      return item;
}
```

Now we are moving to async pattern, so this is the way I am calling the cache helper:

```
    CacheAsideHelper.GetOrAdd(
              async () => await _currencyRepository.GetCurrencyInfo(currencyCode, commandTimeout, taskTimeout, _trackingId),
                    new TimeSpan(Constants.ExpirationDays, 0, 0), true, key);
```

I run some tests, and seems the result is expected. But one of my colleagues said since I am passing async lamda, my cache sometimes may contain `Task<T>`, other than the object T. So somehow I need to wait it.

However, my test seems to give right data, also in my Cache helper code, as I have

```
var item = builder().Result;
```

the cache will always contain real data (other than `Task<T>`),  Am I right or my colleague is correct?

Comment: `Task` is just one class that implements the `IAsyncResult` interface. You could change your signature to `Func<IAsyncResult<T>> builder` to address your colleague's concern, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Why not decorating the `GetOrAdd` method with `async` keyword ? Then you can pass a regular lambda into this method and start it using `Task.Run` on a new 'hot' task with `await`. Not to mention that usage of `.Result` might lead to a dead lock

Comment: @fabjan  do you think current code has the issue my colleague described?

Comment: @daxu I am not sure regarding the issue that your colleague described but honestly I think that this code 'smells'. We don't usually use `async` delegates when passing delegate parameters because depending on certain things this might produce an unexpected result. For example LINQ doesn't know how to work with async delegates which means that it will execute the operation synchronously and we might not expect this behaviour.

Comment: @Fabjan our underlying code (db query, http request) was sync, but now we are converting everything to async, as  indeed it provides better performance. however, there is a learning curve

Comment: You could use [KISS](http://www.principles-wiki.net/principles:keep_it_simple_stupid) and [async all the way down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). To pass an async delegate as parameter to some method isn't really 'simple stupid'

Comment: What is the reasoning of using a builder of type `Func<Task<T>>`? If you are OK with blocking the calling thread while the builder is running, just use a type `Func<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's OK to cache Task itself not the result, see here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/

> Task as a class is very flexible and has resulting benefits. For
>   example, you can await it multiple times, by any number of consumers
>   concurrently. You can store one into a dictionary for any number of
>   subsequent consumers to await in the future, which allows it to be
>   used as a cache for asynchronous results.

Having a task (completed or not) you can await it as many times as you want.  So you can do something like this:

```
public static Task<T> GetOrAdd<T>(Func<Task<T>> builder, string key, TimeSpan expiresIn)
{
      //1. try find task in cache
      //2. if task is failed or cancelled - run builder and put task into cache
      //3. otherwise just return the task
}
```

There are still two problems:

1. exception handling in `builder()`
2. concurrent initialization: it's still possible to run `builder()` few times from different threads

Here you can find possible way to fix both problems: https://github.com/MaximTkachenko/cache-once/blob/master/src/Mtk.CacheOnce/MemoryCacheOnceExtensions.cs